# OnePlus Android loses data whenever on a voice call

Tags: mobile-data, oneplus

My OnePlus Android cellphone (OnePlus 9R Android version 13) always loses the data / internet connection whenever a voice call arrives.

Is there any way to get the phone to continue the data connection even when on a voice call?

Voice and data work in parallel if I am on wifi but otherwise a voice call stops data.

Any setting that would fix this? I am on a 4G network.